# AWS Amplify error import StorageProvider class from aws-amplify

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, storage, aws-amplify

The documentation of AWS Amplify says:

```
import { Storage, StorageProvider } from 'aws-amplify';
export default class MyStorageProvider implements StorageProvider {
```

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage#using-a-custom-plugin

In my angular 8 app, the import fails with this error:

*Module '"node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm"' has no exported member 'StorageProvider'. Did you mean to use 'import StorageProvider from "/node_modules/aws-amplify/lib-esm"' instead?*

Version: "aws-amplify": "^2.2.2"

What's wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

StorageProvider may be exported from `export default StorageProvider` instead of an `export StorageProvider`, so you may have to do:

```
import StorageProvider from 'aws-amplify'
```